# Получение данных всех файлов с одинаковым расширением внутри папки с большой вложенностью Node.JS

Tags: node.js, fs

У меня есть архив внутри которого находится папка, внутри которой большое количество вложенных подпапок, в некоторых из которых лежат текстовые файлы с расширением .po
Этот архив обновляется раз в 2 недели,- меняются подпапки тп.
Я разархивирую его с помощью модуля decompress.

Задача: написать скрипт который получает (дотягивается) до всех файлов с расширением .po, с учетом потенциального изменения папок (вложенностей). Потом нужно будет написать свою логику, которая  собирает все необходимые элементы внутри этих файлов и пушит их в один конечный .json (это я уже сам как-нибудь сделаю, главное понять как дотягиваться до этих файлов)

Ниже показываю как выглядит архитектура разархивированной папки сейчас.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Взять [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) или [`fast-glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-glob)

Comment: @AlexeyTen благодарю, вопрос решён))) слава тебе и пакетным модулям npm :D